# If statment not working as it should do [React hooks]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a simple website with React Hooks. On that website, I want to secure routes, if I'm not Authorized the website should redirect me to login otherwise to de path I want to access. I have the following code where regardless of status is true or false it always goes into the else statement. My question is how is this possible or am I doing something wrong that I haven't noticed?

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "../auth/Login";

function PrivateRoute({ component, ...options }) {
  let status = localStorage.getItem("isAuth");
  console.log("before if ", status);

  if (status === true) {
    console.log("if", status);

    return <Route {...options} component={component} />;
  } else {
    console.log("else", status);

    return <Route {...options} component={Login} />;
  }
}
export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get some values from local storage it is a string so use it likes:

```
  let status = localStorage.getItem("isAuth") === "true";
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you compare the `status` is using the strict equality which is `===` 
So it requires that your status value has to be `boolean` in your case. But when you get it from localStorage, it is a string. Remember `===` **is not the same** with `==`

In many browsers local storage can only store `string`. So when you store the boolean `true` or `false`, it actually stores the strings `"true"` or `"false"`. In order to get back the real boolean values, you can use the JSON.

Or in your case, you can try comparing `status === "true"` and see if that works.

Comment: No, it doesn't work either. I get same console.log as before

Comment: Did you debug it? On debugger are you able to see status has value of "true" ? I guarantee you that it does not!

Comment: Yes, I debugged it and I can see that it is true but it won't come in to if statement.  Solution is found